# Google Workspace SAML apps - Upload self-managed x509 certificate

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, x509, google-workspace

When setting up a SAML app in Google Workspace, a x509 certificate is automatically generated by Google. Is there any way to provide/upload a self-managed certificate for the SAML app instead of using the default x509 certificate auto-generated by Google?

The above is possible in other IdPs such as Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible. Google only allows you to use their own certificates created within the Admin console. You can check that there is no other option to manage the certificates in their [official documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7394709). The only steps provided are related to how to create and delete the certificates from the Security section in the Admin console.